# Загружать Yandex maps из моего сервера или из asset

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Скажите, пожалуйста, могу я загрузить yandex maps на свой сервер, как статику, а подом раздавать клиентам. Чтобы скачивание библиотеки шло не через сервер яндекса, а с моего ?
Естественно что данная карта будет под моим api ключом.

Comment: Ну если вы замените там все ссылки на ресурсы (картинки, css, ...) на абсолютные, то - да, можно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя.
Это будет прямым нарушением условий использования API Яндекс.Карт.

Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [условиями](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/terms/index-docpage?from=mapsapi) использования API и пользовательским [соглашением](https://yandex.ru/legal/maps_api/).